# How to set Encoding in MQ headers using Beanshell in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, ibm-mq, beanshell

I am developing a test script to put a message onto a queue using IBM MQ API 8.0. I am using JMeter 3.1 and Beanshell Sampler for this (see code below).

The problem I am having is setting the "Encoding" field in the MQ headers. I've tried different methods as per API documentation, but nothing worked for me.

Has anyone faced this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Code below:

```
try {
        MQEnvironment.hostname = _hostname;
        MQEnvironment.channel = _channel;
        MQEnvironment.port = _port;
        MQEnvironment.userID = "";
        MQEnvironment.password = "";

        log.info("Using queue manager: " + _qMgr);
        MQQueueManager _queueManager = new MQQueueManager(_qMgr);

        int openOptions = CMQC.MQOO_OUTPUT + CMQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING + CMQC.MQOO_INQUIRE + CMQC.MQOO_BROWSE
            + CMQC.MQOO_SET_IDENTITY_CONTEXT; 

        log.info("Using queue: " + _queueName + ", openOptions: " + openOptions);
        MQQueue queue = _queueManager.accessQueue(_queueName, openOptions);

        log.info("Building message...");
        MQMessage sendmsg = new MQMessage();
        sendmsg.clearMessage();

        // Set MQ MD Headers
        sendmsg.messageType = CMQC.MQMT_DATAGRAM;

        sendmsg.replyToQueueName = _queueName;
        sendmsg.replyToQueueManagerName = _qMgr;

        sendmsg.userId = MQuserId;

        sendmsg.setStringProperty("BAH_FR", fromBIC); // from /AppHdr/Fr/FIId/FinInstnId/BICFI
        sendmsg.setStringProperty("BAH_TO", toBIC); // from /AppHdr/To/FIId/FinInstnId/BICFI
        sendmsg.setStringProperty("BAH_MSGDEFIDR", "pacs.008.001.05"); // from /AppHdr/MsgDefIdr
        sendmsg.setStringProperty("BAH_BIZSVC", "cus.clear.01-" + bizSvc); // from /AppHdr/BizSvcr
        sendmsg.setStringProperty("BAH_PRTY", "NORM"); // priority
        sendmsg.setStringProperty("userId", MQuserId); // user Id

        sendmsg.setStringProperty("ConnectorId", connectorId);
        sendmsg.setStringProperty("Roles", roleId);

        MQPutMessageOptions pmo = new MQPutMessageOptions();    // accept the defaults, same as MQPMO_DEFAULT constant 

        pmo.options = CMQC.MQOO_SET_IDENTITY_CONTEXT;   // set identity context by userId

        // Build message
        String msg = "<NS1> .... </NS1>";

        // MQRFH2 Headers
            sendmsg.format = CMQC.MQFMT_STRING;
            //sendmsg.encoding = CMQC.MQENC_INTEGER_NORMAL | CMQC.MQENC_DECIMAL_NORMAL | CMQC.MQENC_FLOAT_IEEE_NORMAL;
            sendmsg.encoding = 546; // encoding - 546 Windows/Linux

            sendmsg.messageId = msgID.getBytes();
            sendmsg.correlationId = CMQC.MQCI_NONE;

            sendmsg.writeString(msg);

            String messageIdBefore = new String(sendmsg.messageId, "UTF-8");

            log.info("Before put, messageId=[" + messageIdBefore + "]");

            int depthBefore = queue.getCurrentDepth();
            log.info("Queue Depth=" + depthBefore);
            log.info("Putting message on " + _queueName + ".... ");
            queue.put(sendmsg, pmo);
            int depthAfter = queue.getCurrentDepth();
            log.info("Queue Depth=" + depthAfter);

            log.info("**** Done");

            String messageIdAfter = new String(sendmsg.messageId, "UTF-8");
            log.info("After put, messageId=[" + messageIdAfter + "]");

            log.info("Closing connection...");

    } catch (Exception e) {
            log.info("\\nFAILURE - Exception\\n");
            StringWriter errors = new StringWriter();
            e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errors));
            log.error(errors.toString());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are over thinking the problem.  If you are not doing some sort of weird manual character/data conversion then you should be using:

```
sendmsg.encoding = MQC.MQENC_NATIVE;
```